# Is there a way to add a file which has similar ids to a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

I am retrieving grades from a file and I want to insert them to a dictionary with the id as key, what is the best way to do this? Below is the code.

```
from HW08_Swayam_Shah import file_reader
import os
from collections import defaultdict
def grades(path):
    l= defaultdict()
    g = {"A":4.0,"A-":3.75,"B+":3.25,"B":3.0,"B-":2.75,"C+":2.25,"C-":0,"D+":0,"D":0,"D-":0,"F":0}
    for id, course, grade, prof_id in file_reader(
            os.path.join(path, "g.txt"), fields=4, sep='|', header=False):
        for k,v in g.items():
            if grade==k:
                l[id].append(v)
    return l
x = grades("C://Users/Documents/Downloads")
print(x)
```

Below is the input file I am using:

```
10103|SSW 567|A|98765
10103|SSW 564|A-|98764
10103|SSW 687|B|98764
```

As you can see the first field is similar for all columns, but I need this to be my key. Obviously the dictionary will throw a key error, but when the key is same I want it to add it to the next value. Something like:

```
{10103:{A,A-,B}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Changed the variables, v=g[c] is not even related.

Comment: Isn't the desired result supposed to be `{10103: [4.0, 3.75, 3.0]}`?

Comment: True, the problem was the defaultdict(list), but you interchnaged variables, but that's my fault should have written better. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my `v = g[c]` was correct with the original variables.

Comment: Ok it works, sorry to question you, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the factory for the `defaultdict`:

```
l = defaultdict(list)
```

This will create an empty list if the dictionary item doesn't exist, then `append()` will work.

You don't need to loop over the dictionary `g`. Since `grade` is a key, just use `g[grade]` to get the value.

```
def grades(path):
    l= defaultdict(list)
    g = {"A":4.0,"A-":3.75,"B+":3.25,"B":3.0,"B-":2.75,"C+":2.25,"C-":0,"D+":0,"D":0,"D-":0,"F":0}
    for id, course, grade, prof_id in file_reader(
            os.path.join(path, "g.txt"), fields=4, sep='|', header=False):
        grade_numeric = g[grade]
        l[id].append(grade_numeric)
    return l
```